# How to get the actual values from cumulative numbers from day wise data in R

Tags: r, sum, formula

below is my data;

[image]

i wanted to get the actual entry as follows;

[image]

please suggest r solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `diff` :

```
transform(df, entry = c(cum_entry[1], diff(cum_entry)))

#  Day cum_entry entry
#1   1         0     0
#2   2         1     1
#3   3         2     1
#4   3         2     0
#5   4         3     1
#6   4         3     0
```

In `dplyr`, we can use `lag` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate(entry = cum_entry - lag(cum_entry, default = 0))
```

Or `shift` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, entry :=  cum_entry - shift(cum_entry, fill = 0)]
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Day = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), cum_entry = c(0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

the answer is `diff`

```
cumulative <- c(0,1,2,2,3,3)
diff(cumulative)
# [1] 1 1 0 1 0
```